# Проблема с soket в java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!
Есть такая программа

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.text.ParseException;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

public class HttpClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String header = null;
            if (args.length == 0) {
                header = readHeader(System.in);
            } else {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
                header = readHeader(fis);
                fis.close();
            }
            if (header.endsWith("\n"))
                header+='\n';
            //System.out.println("Заголовок: \n" + header);
   /* Запрос отправляется на сервер и мы получаем ответ*/
            String answer = sendRequest(header);
   /* Ответ выводится на консоль */
            System.out.println("Ответ от сервера: \n");
            System.out.write(answer.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Читает поток и возвращает его содержимое в виде строки.
     */
    public static String readHeader(InputStream strm) throws IOException {
        byte[] buff = new byte[64 * 1024];
        int length = strm.read(buff);
        String res = new String(buff, 0, length);
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Отправляет запрос в соответствии с Http заголовком.
     *
     * @return ответ от сервера.
     */
    public static String sendRequest(String httpHeader) throws Exception {
  /* Из http заголовка берется арес сервера */
        String host = null;
        int port = 0;
        try {
            host = getHost(httpHeader);
            port = getPort(host);
            host = getHostWithoutPort(host);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Не удалось получить адрес сервера.", e);
        }
  /* Отправляется запрос на сервер */
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            System.out.println("Создан сокет: " + host + " port:" + port);
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            os.write(httpHeader.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            System.out.println("Заголовок отправлен. \n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Ошибка при отправке запроса: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
  /* Ответ от сервера записывается в результирующую строку */
        String res = null;
        try {
            BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
            int ch = bfr.read();
            while (ch != -1) {
                sbf.append((char) ch);
                ch = bfr.read();
            }
            res = sbf.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Ошибка при чтении ответа от сервера.", e);
        }
        socket.close();
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает имя хоста (при наличии порта, с портом) из http заголовка.
     */
    private static String getHost(String header) throws ParseException {
        final String host = "Host: ";
        final String normalEnd = "\n";
        final String msEnd = "\r\n";

        int s = header.indexOf(host, 0);
        if (s < 0) {
            return "localhost";
        }
        s += host.length();
        int e = header.indexOf(normalEnd, s);
        e = (e > 0) ? e : header.indexOf(msEnd, s);
        if (e < 0) {
            throw new ParseException(
                    "В заголовке запроса не найдено " +
                            "закрывающих символов после пункта Host.",
                    0);
        }
        String res = header.substring(s, e).trim();
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает номер порта.
     */
    private static int getPort(String hostWithPort) {
        int port = hostWithPort.indexOf(":", 0);
        port = (port < 0) ? 80 : Integer.parseInt(hostWithPort
                .substring(port + 1));
        return port;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает имя хоста без порта.
     */
    private static String getHostWithoutPort(String hostWithPort) {
        int portPosition = hostWithPort.indexOf(":", 0);
        if (portPosition < 0) {
            return hostWithPort;
        } else {
            return hostWithPort.substring(0, portPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Отправляю post запрос

```
GET https://api.telegram.org/bot294573807:A213aV0Ggc_ouJc-DbMsVhJzhnXqzWuBZ8w/getupdates HTTP/1.1
Host: api.telegram.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)
```

Получаю вот такой ответ

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

А как сделать перенаправление?

Comment: В заголовках ответа должен быть адрес перенаправления. `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.org/
Content-Type: text/html ...`

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.0
Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2016 03:12:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://api.telegram.org/bot294573807:AAGEaV0Ggc_ouJc-DbMsVhJzhnXqzWuBZ8w/getupdates`
Таже ссылка

Comment: Получив ответ http с кодом результата `301`, извлеките адрес из поля заголовка `Location` и выполните новый запрос на этот адрес (`https://api.telegram.org/bot294573807:AAGEaV0Ggc_ouJc-DbMsVh‌​JzhnXqzWuBZ8w/getupd‌​ates` в Вашем случае). Дополнительно,  поскольку это `Moved permanently`, запомните это перенаправление и следующие запросы сразу отправляйте сразу на новый адрес, Кажется именно так желательно поступать c `Moved permanently`.